# How can i merge 2 lists to 1 so i can sort it together in c#?

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I want to make an application where I can type a word and then a number. After typing all I want I want an output of them sorted alphabetical. The problem is that the words sort but the numbers don't sort with them because they are 2 different lists. How can i merge this 2 lists? I don't want to add them together like AddRange I need the out put like Console.WriteLine ("x{0}+" "+"{1}", numbers, words.

I've tried words.Sort(); but it just sorted the words and not both. So how can I merge the 2 lists?

The question is probably clear but in case you need some code there it is:

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Threading;

  namespace zutaten
  {
      namespace mengen
      {
          class Program
          {
          static int hello;
          static List<string> zutaten = new List<string>();
          static List<int> mengen = new List<int>();
          public static int memo;
          public static int d = 1;
          static List<string> zusammen = new List<string>();
          static public bool Main(string[] args)
          {

              bool fertig = false;

            while (!fertig)
            {
                var wert = Console.ReadLine();
                if (wert != "f")
                {
                    if (Gleich(zutaten, mengen))//zutaten.Count == mengen.Count)
                    {
                        if (KeineZutaten(wert))//int.TryParse(wert, out int keineZutat))
                        {
                            KeineZutatenAussage(wert);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (Beinhaltet(wert)) //zutaten.Contains(wert)
                            {
                                Removen(wert);
                                //    int index = zutaten.IndexOf(wert);
                                //    zutaten.RemoveAt(index);
                                //    mengen.RemoveAt(index);
                            }
                            //-------
                            Zutathinzufügen(wert);
                            //zutaten.Add(wert);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (ParseMenge(wert, out memo))//int.TryParse(wert, out int menge))
                        {
                            Mengehinzufügen(memo);// mengen.Add(menge);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Mengepluseins(mengen);
                            //mengen.Add(1);

                            //--------

                            if (Beinhaltet(wert))
                            {
                                Removen(wert);
                                //    int index = zutaten.IndexOf(wert);
                                //    zutaten.RemoveAt(index);
                                //    mengen.RemoveAt(index);

                            }
                            //------
                            Zutathinzufügen(wert);
                            //zutaten.Add(wert);

                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    fertig = Fertigt();

                    if (!Gleich(zutaten, mengen))
                    {
                        Mengepluseins(mengen);
                    }

                    Forschleife(zutaten);

                    //for (int i = 0; i < zutaten.Count; i++)
                    //{
                    //    Console.WriteLine("x{0} {1}", mengen[i], zutaten[i]);
                    //}
                }
            }
        }





        public static string MeineMethode()
        {
            return "string";
        }

        public static bool Gleich(List<string> variable1, List<int> variable2)
        {
            return variable1.Count == variable2.Count;
        }

        public static bool KeineZutaten(string wert1)
        {
            return int.TryParse(wert1, out hello);
        }

        public static void KeineZutatenAussage(string wert2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ist keine Zutat", wert2);
        }

        public static bool Beinhaltet(string hulu)
        {
            return zutaten.Contains(hulu);
        }

        public static void Removen(string wertt)
        {
            int index = zutaten.IndexOf(wertt);
            zutaten.RemoveAt(index);
            mengen.RemoveAt(index);
        }

        public static void Zutathinzufügen(string werttt)
        {
            zutaten.Add(werttt);
        }
        //    int index = zutaten.IndexOf(wert);
        //    zutaten.RemoveAt(index);
        //    mengen.RemoveAt(index);

        //int.TryParse(wert, out int keineZutat
        //zutaten.Add(wert);

        public static bool ParseMenge(string wert1, out int var2)
        {
            return int.TryParse(wert1, out var2);
        }
        //int.TryParse(wert, out int menge))

        public static void Mengehinzufügen(int var1)
        {
            mengen.Add(var1);
        }
        // mengen.Add(menge);

        public static void Mengepluseins(List<int> mengen)
        {
            mengen.Add(d);
        }
        //mengen.Add(1);

        public static bool Fertigt()
        {
            return true;
        }
        //fertig = true;

        public static bool Mengeungleichzutaten(List<string> variable1, List<int> variable2)
        {
            return variable1.Count != variable2.Count;
        }                                                                                                      
        //if (mengen.Count != zutaten.Count)                                                                   
        //{                                                                                                    
        //    mengen.Add(1);                                                                                                                    
        //}

        public static void Forschleife(List<string> hey)
        {

            zutaten.Sort();
            for (int i = 0; i < hey.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("x{0}"+" "+"{1}, mengen[i], zutaten[i]);
            }
}
```

Input example :

```
Pork[Enter]
3[Enter] 
Tomatoes[Enter]
6[Enter]
Potatoes[Enter]
2[Enter]
```

Expected output :

```
3x Pork 
2x Potatoes 
6x Tomatoes
```

Current output :

```
3x Pork 
6x Potatoes 
2x Tomatoes
```

Comment: instead `List<string>` and `List<int>` use `List<MyClassStringNumberPair>` (or `List<Tuple<string,int>>`)

Comment: If you use arrays instead of lists, you could use [`Array.Sort(Array, Array)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_Sort_System_Array_System_Array_) to sort both arrays simultaneously.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I think you are right. You can post this as answer, I deleted my answer

Comment: @Cid He might not be able to use arrays, though - I'll wait for OP to respond. Also, I think that u/Selvin has the best idea.

Comment: @MatthewWatson sure I'll try it :)

Comment: @Seajanjan can you give us some sample input with expected output ? Reading some german code doesn't help at all

Comment: Input: Pork [Enter]
3 [Enter]
Tomatos [Enter]
6[Enter]
Potatoes [Enter]
2[Enter]
Output:
3x Pork
2x Potatoes
6x Tomatoes
(this should be it but instead the is:)
3x Pork
6x Potatoes
2x Tomatoes

Comment: use [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57819015/edit) please, this is barely readable in comments and it's part of the question

Comment: @Cid done at the end of the code.

Comment: You enter first the product, then its quantity and it should display the product along with its quantity ordered by product name ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these can be arrays, then you can use the native sort command to sort the two arrays according to one of them. This example sorts by the scores:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] classScores = new int[]{30,50,25,39,62};
            string[] studentNames = new string[]{"Jim","John","Mary","Peter","Sarah"};
                Array.Sort(classScores, studentNames);   // sort both according to scores
            for (int i = 0; i < classScores.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(classScores[i] + " " + studentNames[i]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [`SortedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) to store your values. The key being the product name, the value its quantity. This will be automatically sorted by key.

```
static SortedDictionary<string, int> GetProducts()
{
    //                               Type of the
    //                                   key     
    //                                    |  Type of the
    //                                    |    value
    //                                    |      |
    //                                    v      v
    var Products = new SortedDictionary<string, int>();

    while (true)
    {
        var product = "";
        int quantity;
        // First, ask the user to enter a product. If he enters nothing, ask again
        while (product == "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a product name or f to finish");
            product = Console.ReadLine();
            if (product == "f")
                return Products; // we are done, we can return the SortedDictionary
        }

        // Now, get the quantity
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Please enter a quantity for {product}");
          // Ask again if the user enters an invalid number
        } while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out quantity));
        // Store the informations in the SortedDictionary
        Products[product] = quantity;
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    // Get the products
    var Products = GetProducts();
    // Display them
    foreach (var key in Products.Keys)
        Console.WriteLine($"{Products[key]}x {key}");
}
```

Input :

```
Please enter a product name or f to finish
Pork
Please enter a quantity for Pork
3
Please enter a product name or f to finish
Tomatoes
Please enter a quantity for Tomatoes
6
Please enter a product name or f to finish
Potatoes
Please enter a quantity for Potatoes
2
Please enter a product name or f to finish
f
```

Output :

```
3x Pork
2x Potatoes
6x Tomatoes
```